# Google Sheet match category with multiple keywords to strings

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

How do I match a category list(column `D`) with 3 columns of keywords (columns `A B C`) to a list of strings(column `H`) and have the result of column `I`?

I was thinking vlookup and tried something like this, but looks like it doesn't work:

```
=vlookup("*"&A2:A&"*"&B2:B&"*"&C2:C&"*",H2:H,1)
```

I was also considering `QUERY`, but I don't think that can match by row either.

Any help is appreciated!

spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHT5d4KkZ49csitkICUd7ANwjWMZXk9GAZA_5pVZlrs/edit#gid=0

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(H2:H, "-")), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:C))),,1), {{A2:A;B2:B;C2:C},{D2:D;D2:D;D2:D}}, 2, 0))&
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(H2:H, "-")), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:C))),,2), {{A2:A;B2:B;C2:C},{D2:D;D2:D;D2:D}}, 2, 0))&
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(H2:H, "-")), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:C))),,3), {{A2:A;B2:B;C2:C},{D2:D;D2:D;D2:D}}, 2, 0)), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, UNIQUE(IFERROR({
 VLOOKUP(INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(H2:H, "-")), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:C))),,1), {{A2:A;B2:B;C2:C},{D2:D;D2:D;D2:D}}, 2, 0);
 VLOOKUP(INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(H2:H, "-")), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:C))),,2), {{A2:A;B2:B;C2:C},{D2:D;D2:D;D2:D}}, 2, 0);
 VLOOKUP(INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(H2:H, "-")), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:C))),,3), {{A2:A;B2:B;C2:C},{D2:D;D2:D;D2:D}}, 2, 0)}))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering this and sorry about the mods fighting. One problem I found (I should have provided a better set of list in `H`) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHT5d4KkZ49csitkICUd7ANwjWMZXk9GAZA_5pVZlrs/edit#gid=0 if I have `bling_bang_pay` it mistakenly categorizes it as `IncomeInequality` due to the `pay` keyword. I'd like it to match all available keywords.

Comment: well, yes that's kinda expected behavior. `bling_bang_pay` has no `-` so its treated as 1 phrase eg the `SPLIT` is not applied and `REGEXEXTRACT` is in mode of finding partial matches not full matches (full matches fould be: `"^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, A2:C)&"$"` instead of: `TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:C)`